What is adding all this extra code in the website's source in Shopify?
I have this code in the theme.liquid file:
{{ shop.metafields.loox.global_html_head }}
  </head>

  <style class="loop-style">
    {% render 'loop-widget.css' %}
  </style>

The raw source code of the page (Ctrl + U) has this code:
<script>var loox_global_hash = 'HASH_VALUE';</script><script>var visitor_level_referral = {"active":true,"rtl":false,"position":"right","button_text":"Get €20","button_bg_color":"323620","button_text_color":"ffffff","display_on_home_page":true,"display_on_product_page":true,"display_on_cart_page":true,"display_on_other_pages":true,"hide_on_mobile":false,"sidebar_visible":true,"orientation":"default"};
</script><style>.loox-reviews-default { max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; }.loox-rating .loox-icon { color:#f5c20c; }
:root { --lxs-rating-icon-color: #f5c20c; }</style>

// Lots of JavaScript

<style class="loop-style">
    .loop-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
... CSS for loop-style

I commented out this line:
{{ shop.metafields.loox.global_html_head }}

but the only code that was removed is:
<script>var loox_global_hash = 'HASH_VALUE';</script><script>var visitor_level_referral = {"active":true,"rtl":false,"position":"right","button_text":"Get €20","button_bg_color":"323620","button_text_color":"ffffff","display_on_home_page":true,"display_on_product_page":true,"display_on_cart_page":true,"display_on_other_pages":true,"hide_on_mobile":false,"sidebar_visible":true,"orientation":"default"};
</script><style>.loox-reviews-default { max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; }.loox-rating .loox-icon { color:#f5c20c; }
:root { --lxs-rating-icon-color: #f5c20c; }</style>

There are some app blocks and snippets that are adding the code but there are also huge code sections that I have no idea where they are coming from.
There are many scripts like this:
<script id="web-pixels-manager-setup">... lots of code
<script class="analytics">... lots of code
<script class="boomerang">... lots of code
<script
  defer
  src="https://floryamor.com/cdn/shopifycloud/perf-kit/shopify-perf-kit-1.0.0.min.js"
  data-application="storefront-renderer"
  data-shop-id="SHOP_ID"
  data-render-region="gcp-europe-west3"
  data-page-type="index"
  data-theme-instance-id="INSTANCE_ID"
  data-monorail-region="shop_domain"
  data-resource-timing-sampling-rate="10"
></script>
</head>

How can I find out where all this other code is coming from?
